# Scala Swing: how to get child component form Borderpanel

Tags: scala, scala-swing

How do I get the child component for a particular position on a Scala Swing BorderPanel? I can place components OK. In this particular case I want to check the component at BorderPanel.Position.Centre. Also am I right that there can only be one child component or a null at each position: North, East etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `layout` is a Map from component to position, so the following works (not sure if there's an easier way):

```
import scala.swing.SimpleSwingApplication
import scala.swing.MainFrame
import scala.swing.BorderPanel
import scala.swing.Label

object BorderLayoutTest extends SimpleSwingApplication {

  def top = new MainFrame {    
    contents = new BorderPanel {

      val label = new Label("hi")

      import BorderPanel.Position._
      layout(label) = Center

      println("North: " + layout.find(_._2 == North))   //None
      println("Center: "+ layout.find(_._2 == Center))  //Some( ... )
    } 
  }  
}
```